# Switch desktop with keyboard based on active window instead of mouse position on macOS

Tags: macos

I'm using default keyboard shortcuts to switch between desktops. Unfortunately, since I use several monitors, I have to move the mouse to the monitor on which I want to switch desktops. Is it possible to do this using the current active window instead of the mouse position? I.e. the chosen monitor for the desktop switch would be the one containing the active window.